# Parse an xml (created from a json) with many intertwined arrays using xslt

Tags: arrays, loops, xslt, key, repeat

I would like to write an xslt parser to parse this xml, which has multiple inner arrays as it was created from a json payload. Any help is appreciated. I am open to use Xslt 1.0 - 3.0 as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dynamic>

    <customer_name>XYZ</customer_name>  
    <state>
        <results>
            <map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
                <number key="totalCount">3</number>
                <array key="result">
                    <map>
                        <string key="metricId">(Metric1:splitBy():sort(value(auto,descending)):limit(20)):limit(100):names</string>
                        <number key="dataPointCountRatio">0.0193479</number>
                        <array key="data">
                            <map>
                                <array key="timestamps">
                                    <number>t1</number>
                                    <number>t2</number>
                                </array>
                                <array key="values">
                                    <number>a1</number>
                                    <number>a2</number>
                                </array>
                            </map>
                        </array>
                    </map>
                    <map>
                        <string key="metricId">(Metric2:splitBy():sort(value(auto,descending)):limit(20)):limit(100):names</string>
                        <number key="dataPointCountRatio">0.0187083</number>
                        <array key="data">
                            <map>
                                <array key="timestamps">
                                    <number>t1</number>
                                    <number>t2</number>
                                </array>
                                <array key="values">
                                    <number>b1</number>
                                    <number>b2</number>
                                </array>
                            </map>
                        </array>
                    </map>
                    <map>
                        <string key="metricId">(Metric3:splitBy():sort(value(auto,descending)):limit(20)):limit(100):names</string>
                        <number key="dataPointCountRatio">0.0217464</number>
                        <array key="data">
                            <map>
                                <array key="timestamps">
                                    <number>t1</number>
                                    <number>t2</number>
                                </array>
                                <array key="values">
                                    <number>c1</number>
                                    <number>c2</number>
                                </array>
                            </map>
                        </array>
                    </map>
                </array>
            </map>
        </results>
        <count>1</count>
    </state>
</dynamic>
```

and the Expected response is something like this , 2 payloads

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<json>
    <map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" key="_source">
        <string key="customer_name">XYZ</string>
        <string key="common_date">t1</string>
        <string key="metric1">a1</string>
        <string key="metric2">b1</string>
        <string key="metric3">c1</string>
        <string key="@timestamp">current timestamp</string>
    </map>
</json>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<json>
    <map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" key="_source">
        <string key="customer_name">XYZ</string>
        <string key="common_date">t2</string>
        <string key="metric1">a2</string>
        <string key="metric2">b2</string>
        <string key="metric3">c2</string>
        <string key="@timestamp">current timestamp</string>
    </map>
</json>
```

Tried to work on transforms but got only the first element in the arrays. Unable to get further elements.

Comment: Please explain the required logic in words - how would you do this manually? And where are the values of `common_date` and `@timestamp` supposed to come from?

Comment: Sure @michael.hor257k thanks for pointing that out.. i changed the expected payload. So basically need to use arrays to iterate over the recursive arrays.. in above format.  And then create those many payloads as the number of timestamps. So its like create a response using t1,a1,b1,c1 and the next using t2,a2,b2,c2

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to work with this XML, rather than working directly with the JSON from which it was created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very difficult to understand what in your example is real and what is just an example. I am guessing (!) you want to do something like:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
exclude-result-prefixes="map">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/dynamic">
    <xsl:variable name="customer_name" select="customer_name" />
    <xsl:variable name="timestamps" select="descendant::map:array[@key='timestamps'][1]" />
    <xsl:variable name="value-arrays" select="//map:array[@key='values']" />
    <!-- a result for each value in timestamps -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$timestamps/map:number">
        <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
        <result href="file_{$i}.xml">
            <json>
                <map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" key="_source">
                    <string key="customer_name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$customer_name"/>
                    </string>
                    <string key="common_date">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </string>
                    <!-- take the i-th value from each value array --> 
                    <xsl:for-each select="$value-arrays">
                        <xsl:variable name="j" select="position()" />
                        <string key="metric{$j}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="map:number[$i]"/>
                        </string>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <string key="@timestamp">
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-dateTime()"/>
                    </string>
                </map>
            </json> 
        </result>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, this will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result href="file_1.xml">
   <json>
      <map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" key="_source">
         <string key="customer_name">XYZ</string>
         <string key="common_date">t1</string>
         <string key="metric1">a1</string>
         <string key="metric2">b1</string>
         <string key="metric3">c1</string>
         <string key="@timestamp">2023-03-08T17:17:37Z</string>
      </map>
   </json>
</result>
<result href="file_2.xml">
   <json>
      <map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" key="_source">
         <string key="customer_name">XYZ</string>
         <string key="common_date">t2</string>
         <string key="metric1">a2</string>
         <string key="metric2">b2</string>
         <string key="metric3">c2</string>
         <string key="@timestamp">2023-03-08T17:17:37Z</string>
      </map>
   </json>
</result>
```

Change `result` to `xsl:result-document` in order to  create a separate file for each "payload".

Comment: Sure thanks. One deviation, if for above payload the input payload the metric1/2/3 is actually some text like MetricAB, MetricCD , MetricDE and it needs to be pulled from this tag, then how can i modify this xslt line <string key="metric{$j}">? Thanks in advance.

<string key="metricId">(MetricAB:splitBy():sort(value(auto,descending)):limit(20)):limit(100):names</string>

Comment: It depends on how exactly it needs to be "pulled" from the text that contains it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't grasped whether that input is generic or always as shown; for that shown input structure you kind of get what you want with XSLT 3 ([demo](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Afn%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-skip%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22results%2Ffn%3Amap%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Afor-each-group%20select%3D%22.%22%20group-by%3D%22descendant%3A%3Afn%3Aarray%5B%40key%20%3D%20%27timestamps%27%5D%2Ffn%3Anumber%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22pos%22%20select%3D%22position%28%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aresult-document%20href%3D%22payload-%7B%24pos%7D.xml%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cjson%20xmlns%3D%22%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cmap%20key%3D%22_source%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cstring%20key%3D%22customer_name%22%3E%7Bancestor%3A%3Adynamic%2Fcustomer_name%7D%3C%2Fstring%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cstring%20key%3D%22common_date%22%3E%7Bcurrent-grouping-key%28%29%7D%3C%2Fstring%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22.%2F%2Ffn%3Aarray%5B%40key%20%3D%20%27values%27%5D%2Ffn%3Anumber%5B%24pos%5D%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fmap%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fjson%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aresult-document%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Afor-each-group%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22fn%3Aarray%5B%40key%20%3D%20%27values%27%5D%2Ffn%3Anumber%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cstring%20key%3D%22metric%7Bposition%28%29%7D%22%3E%7B.%7D%3C%2Fstring%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cdynamic%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccustomer_name%3EXYZ%3C%2Fcustomer_name%3E%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cstate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cresults%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cmap%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cnumber%20key%3D%22totalCount%22%3E3%3C%2Fnumber%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Carray%20key%3D%22result%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cmap%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cstring%20key%3D%22metricId%22%3E%28Metric1%3AsplitBy%28%29%3Asort%28value%28auto%2Cdescending%29%29%3Alimit%2820%29%29%3Alimit%28100%29%3Anames%3C%2Fstring%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cnumber%20key%3D%22dataPointCountRatio%22%3E0.0193479%3C%2Fnumber%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Carray%20key%3D%22data%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cmap%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Carray%20key%3D%22timestamps%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cnumber%3Et1%3C%2Fnumber%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cnumber%3Et2%3C%2Fnumber%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Farray%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Carray%20key%3D%22values%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cnumber%3Ea1%3C%2Fnumber%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cnumber%3Ea2%3C%2Fnumber%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Farray%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fmap%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Farray%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fmap%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cmap%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cstring%20key%3D%22metricId%22%3E%28Metric2%3AsplitBy%28%29%3Asort%28value%28auto%2Cdescending%29%29%3Alimit%2820%29%29%3Alimit%28100%29%3Anames%3C%2Fstring%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cnumber%20key%3D%22dataPointCountRatio%22%3E0.0187083%3C%2Fnumber%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Carray%20key%3D%22data%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cmap%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Carray%20key%3D%22timestamps%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cnumber%3Et1%3C%2Fnumber%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cnumber%3Et2%3C%2Fnumber%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Farray%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Carray%20key%3D%22values%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cnumber%3Eb1%3C%2Fnumber%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cnumber%3Eb2%3C%2Fnumber%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Farray%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fmap%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Farray%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fmap%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cmap%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cstring%20key%3D%22metricId%22%3E%28Metric3%3AsplitBy%28%29%3Asort%28value%28auto%2Cdescending%29%29%3Alimit%2820%29%29%3Alimit%28100%29%3Anames%3C%2Fstring%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cnumber%20key%3D%22dataPointCountRatio%22%3E0.0217464%3C%2Fnumber%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Carray%20key%3D%22data%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cmap%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Carray%20key%3D%22timestamps%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cnumber%3Et1%3C%2Fnumber%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cnumber%3Et2%3C%2Fnumber%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Farray%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Carray%20key%3D%22values%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cnumber%3Ec1%3C%2Fnumber%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cnumber%3Ec2%3C%2Fnumber%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Farray%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fmap%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Farray%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fmap%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Farray%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fmap%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fresults%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ccount%3E1%3C%2Fcount%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fstate%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fdynamic%3E&input-type=XML)) and

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="results/fn:map">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="." group-by="descendant::fn:array[@key = 'timestamps']/fn:number">
      <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
      <xsl:result-document href="payload-{$pos}.xml">
       <json xmlns="">
        <map key="_source" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
          <string key="customer_name">{ancestor::dynamic/customer_name}</string>
          <string key="common_date">{current-grouping-key()}</string>
          <xsl:apply-templates select=".//fn:array[@key = 'values']/fn:number[$pos]"/>
        </map>
       </json>
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="fn:array[@key = 'values']/fn:number">
    <string key="metric{position()}">{.}</string>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I couldn't tell where `<string key="@timestamp">current timestamp</string>` comes from so I have left it out.

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen thank you much. The above code somehow is giving me stylesheet compilation errors.

Comment: @mangola2023, which error exactly, with which XSLT 3 processor?